# How to split a string in each row

Tags: r

What would be the best way to change the following `V2` column:

```
head(t2g)
              V1                    V2
1: lcl|ScwjSwM_1  sp|Q8RWZ5|SD25_ARATH
2: lcl|ScwjSwM_2 sp|Q9LH84|AATP5_ARATH
```

into:

```
head(t2g)
              V1      V2
1: lcl|ScwjSwM_1  Q8RWZ5
2: lcl|ScwjSwM_2  Q9LH84
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Would be nice if you showed us what you have coded so far, don’t expect us to do work for you

Comment: We rly need to know what you tried that didn't work to not waste our own time. Unless your time is worth more than ours. If so, we all have consulting fees.

Comment: I was thinking to split with `sep = "|"` each row in `V2` which would provide me with 3 parts. I would like to keep the part[2].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `strplit` with `sapply`:

```
t2g$V2 = sapply(strsplit(t2g$V2, split = "|", fixed = TRUE), `[`, 2)
```

or with `gsub`:

```
t2g$V2 = gsub("^.*[|](\\w+)[|].*$", "\\1", t2g$V2)
```

**Result:**

```
> t2g
             V1     V2
1 lcl|ScwjSwM_1 Q8RWZ5
2 lcl|ScwjSwM_2 Q9LH84
```

**Data:**

```
t2g = read.table(text = "              V1                    V2
                 lcl|ScwjSwM_1  sp|Q8RWZ5|SD25_ARATH
                 lcl|ScwjSwM_2 sp|Q9LH84|AATP5_ARATH", header = TRUE, 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: In `sapply`, I'm supplying the argument `2` to the `[` function for each element of `strplit`. This is equivalent to taking the 2nd element of each `strplit` element with `[2]`.